# Adding margins around GridLayout cells

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am trying to figure out how to add margins around fragments that are added to a GridLayout.

```
GridLayout gridLayout = mRegionPage.findViewById(R.id.xglRegionPage);

GridLayout.MarginLayoutParams foo = 
        new GridLayout.MarginLayoutParams(GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                          GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

foo.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
gridLayout.setLayoutParams(foo);
```

The xml resource looks like

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/xglRegionPage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rowCount="2"
    ... />
```

I get a fault that is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams 
            cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:186)
    at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onMeasure(HorizontalScrollView.java:491)
```

If I comment out the line that sets the layout params, there is no fault.

```
GridLayout gridLayout = mRegionPage.findViewById(R.id.xglRegionPage);

GridLayout.MarginLayoutParams foo = 
        new GridLayout.MarginLayoutParams(GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                          GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

foo.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
///gridLayout.setLayoutParams(foo);
```

The problem for me is I do not use a single FrameLayout in any project.  I checked all of the toolkit parts I use and none of them are sub classes from FrameLayout.

Is there an alternative way to accomplish this?

How did FrameLayout get mixed up in all of this?  Or is GridLayout built around the FrameLayout?

If I want to have two rows of cards with some space between them do  have to use two linear layouts?

It has been suggested that I add margins to the base of the fragment, which I already have with no effect.  They look like:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

  android:id="@+id/clRegionFragment"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@drawable/excited_shape"
  android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
```

Comment: Your `GridLayout` is apparently inside a `HorizontalScrollView`, which extends `FrameLayout`. `GridLayout`'s `LayoutParams` are not compatible with `HorizontalScrollView`'s `LayoutParams`, which are `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` because of the inheritance, and is why you're seeing that in the stack trace. If you want margins around each child of the `GridLayout`, then you want to set those margins on the children, not the `GridLayout` itself. The simplest way to do that is to add `android:layout_margin*` attributes on the root `<View>` in those child layouts.

Comment: Only problem is, that doesn't work for a gridLayout.  I'm not adding the parameters to the HorizontalScrollView, I don't even care about the ScrollView.  How did it get involved,  I added them to the grid layout?  Are the parameters passed up the hierarchy?  Is that why I'm seeing the stack trace?

Comment: How do you mean, exactly?

Comment: I tried that so many times and it has no effect.

Comment: "I don't even care about the ScrollView. How did it get involved, I added them to the grid layout?" – A `View`'s `LayoutParams` tell the `View`'s parent how to lay out that child. When you set those `LayoutParams` on the `GridLayout`, its parent – the `HorizontalScrollView` – is trying to use those to know how to lay out the `GridLayout`, and that's where it's choking. As far as my suggestion having no effect, gimme a minute to do some research. I don't use `GridLayout` very much.

Comment: OK, just had a quick look through the source code, and there's no reason those margins shouldn't work there. I also ran a quick test, and it works as expected for me. Are you sure you're inflating the layout correctly in the `Fragment`? In `onCreateView()`, you need to pass the `ViewGroup` parameter as the parent in the `inflate()` call; e.g., `inflater.inflater(R.layout.fragment, container, false)`.

Comment: That's exactly how they are inflated.

Comment: I just figured out something.  I have to pass the GridLayout.LayoutParams, to get the row and column correctly.  If I comment this out then ithe root margins are correct.  I figured it all out.  I added the margind to the GridLayout.Layout params that I have to add to the root to get the row correct.  Once I do this, it all works correctly.

Comment: It sounds like you might be creating a new `LayoutParams`, instead of using the one that will already be on the inflated `View`, with the correct margins. If so, then instead, do `GridLayout.LayoutParams lp = (GridLayout.LayoutParams) inflatedView.getLayoutParams();`, and set the column and row on that.

Comment: I have to create the row and column before I inflate the Fragment.  I just used the GridLayout.Layout Params because it was convenient.   I can just pas the row and col to the fragment and do as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author to move the solution to the answer space)*.

The problem was I added in GridLayout.LayoutParams that I made up before the fragment was inflated, thereby eliminating any of the values from the fragment xml. Instead I added the row and column for the grid position to the fragment and after the fragment was inflated, I set the parameters for the Grid row and column spec.